# Social Sign On for Salesforce Reg Handler Class and Test Class-System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, failing-tests, code

My org is setting up social sign on with Google and I am running into an error I have never seen before: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Here is my class and test class for reference.

```
global class AutocreatedRegHandler1537799224416 implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{
//https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9060G0000005dc5QAA
global boolean canCreateUser(Auth.UserData data) {
  return false;
}

global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){    
    if(!canCreateUser(data)) {
    return null;
  }

  if(data.attributeMap.containsKey('sfdc_networkid')) {

    Account a = [SELECT Id FROM account WHERE name='Acme'];
    Contact c = new Contact();
    c.accountId = a.Id;
    c.email = data.email;
    c.firstName = data.firstName;
    c.lastName = data.lastName;
    insert(c);

    User u = new User();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Community User'];
    u.username = data.username + '@suyati.test.com ';
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    String alias = data.username;

    if(alias.length() > 8) {
      alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
    }
    u.alias = alias;

    u.languagelocalekey = 'en_US';
    u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    u.profileId = p.Id;
    u.contactId = c.Id;
    return u;
  } else {

    User u = new User();
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name='Standard User'];

    u.username = data.username + '@myorg.com';
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    String alias = data.username;

    if(alias.length() > 8) {
      alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
    }
    u.alias = alias;
    u.languagelocalekey = 'en_US';
    u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    u.profileId = p.Id;
    return u;
  }
}

global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
  User u = new User(id=userId);


  u.email = data.email;
  u.lastName = data.lastName;
  u.firstName = data.firstName;

  update(u);
}
}
```

And the test class

```
    @isTest
private class AutocreatedRegHandler1537799224416Test 
{
static testMethod void testCreateAndUpdateUser() 
{
AutocreatedRegHandler1537799224416  handler = new AutocreatedRegHandler1537799224416 ();

 Auth.UserData sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testId', 'testFirst', 'testLast', 
'testFirst testLast', 'testuser@example.org', 
null, 'testuserlong', 'en_US', 'google', 
null, new Map<String, String>{'language' => 'en_US'});
User u = handler.createuser(null, sampleData);
System.assertEquals('testuser@suyati.test.com', u.userName);
System.assertEquals('testuser@example.org', u.email);
System.assertEquals('testLast', u.lastName);
System.assertEquals('testFirst', u.firstName);
System.assertEquals('ttest', u.alias);
String uid = u.id;

sampleData = new Auth.UserData('testNewId', 'testNewFirst', 'testNewLast',
'testNewFirst testNewLast', 'testnewuser@example.org', null, 'testnewuserlong', 'en_US', 'facebook',
null, new Map<String, String>{});
update(u);

User updatedUser = [SELECT userName, email, firstName, lastName, alias FROM user WHERE id=:uid];
System.assertEquals('testnewuserlong@salesforce.com', updatedUser.userName);
System.assertEquals('testnewuser@example.org', updatedUser.email);
System.assertEquals('testNewLast', updatedUser.lastName);
System.assertEquals('testNewFirst', updatedUser.firstName);
System.assertEquals('testnewu', updatedUser.alias);
}
}
```

Comment: On which line is the `NullPointerException` thrown? This is a very common error (see [numerous questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=NullPointerException) on SFSE), and is unlikely to be specific to SSO.

Comment: Line 13 - System.assertEquals('testuser@suyati.test.com', u.userName);

Answer (score 1):

So if you have a `NullPointerException` here:

```
User u = handler.createuser(null, sampleData);
System.assertEquals('testuser@suyati.test.com', u.userName);
```

on the assertion, there's exactly one possibility: `u` is null. So our next step is to look at where `u` comes from, your `createUser()` method, to determine why.

The answer turns out to be right at the top of your file:

```
global boolean canCreateUser(Auth.UserData data) {
  return false;
}

global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){    
    if(!canCreateUser(data)) {
    return null;
  }
```

Your creation class is hard-coded to return `false` for `canCreateUser()`, and hard-coded to return `null` when it cannot create a user.

I'm not sure what business logic you intend to implement for `canCreateUser()`, but it looks like you need to finish fleshing out this code before you can embark on tests - or at least remove the hard-coded `false`.

Edit - based on your comments, this is auto-generated code, rather than being copied from the Salesforce Developer Forum. This code is not complete; it is a skeleton that you need to flesh out and complete based on your business requirements. As written, the code is not usable *or* testable because it is hard-coded to fail.

Comment: I'm not a developer so I'm not really sure what to do. Our Google Admin set up a SAML with Salesforce and it generated that code and now our code coverage is all messed up so I am just trying to cover the code.

Comment: If you don't have a team member that knows or is willing to learn Apex, I would suggest that you contract with a developer.

Comment: The code that you're using here is a skeleton. It needs to be fleshed out to work correctly.